# ASP.NET MVC with EF and the Dispose Pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm writing an ASP.NET MVC application with EF. I have some questions regarding whether or not my approach is reasonable. *Note: I simplified my basic structure for this question, in realitiy everything is coupled more loosely.*

Let's assume a View that allows a user to change properties of a complex domain model. The data originates from the Database (via EF) and has to be written back again in the end.

From my understanding, each request results in a new controller instance being called. Therefore, I'm using the 'Dispose Pattern' described [here as Option 2](https://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2013/03/27/managing-entity-framework-dbcontext-lifetime-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx), which ensures a new DbContext for every request:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private MyContext repo = new MyContext();

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        this.repo.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    //more code...
}
```

Now there is a `public ActionResult Edit(elementId)` method on the controller that will fetch an element from the database and displays an editor for it. Once this request is finished, any reference to the Dbcontext is gone, but I still have access to the Entity-Object fetched from the DB as **I store it in my session**.

Later on the user presses a 'Save' button on the View. The request to the Save-method of my Controller once again creates a new instance of the Controller and therefore a new DbContext. The Entity-object stored in my session is retrieved and its properties are modified according to the user's input. To save the new state to the database, I have to attach it to the new context:

```
public void Save()
{
    this.repo.MyTable.Attach(myEntity);
    myEntity.Name = "New Name";
    this.repo.SaveChanges();
}
```

This can only work once the old Controller with the original DbContext of `myEntity` has been disposed, otherwise 'Attach' would fail (unable to attach Entity to two contexts). **I'm concerned whether or not I can rely on the old DbContext being disposed here.**

**Also:** I know that using an IoC framework would be an alternative. How would that apply to my situation, what would be the benefits?

Comment: Your [link](http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2013/03/27/managing-entity-framework-dbcontext-lifetime-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx)  lays it out. Not sure what you mean by storing your fetched entity in session - no need for that just pass it to your view. Better yet use [ViewModels](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2013/03/Why-You-Never-Expose-Your-Domain-Model-As-Your-MVC-Model/).

Comment: It is best to keep DbContext instances open as short as possible, only instantiate a DbContext object if you really need it and close it as soon when you no longer need to interact with the database for that particular request. From an architectural point of view, I would advise you to apply IoC along with a service layer which will handle your web requests, therefore making your controllers 'fat-free'.

Comment: Try exploring Unity.Mvc5. It's a very easy to use IoC Container and best supported for MVC. It provides object lifetime management per request which suits your requirement very well. You will not have to worry about disposing DbContext if you are using this.

Comment: To each his own; DI containers are often very personal choices. However, I don't know if there's much basis in the statement that Unity is the *best* supported container for MVC. Ninject works *very* well with MVC, Web Api, etc, and is just as simple if not simpler to use.

Comment: @Steve Greene: I might need to clarify on what I meant with "storing the entity in the session". I store my ViewModel in the session which also knows the ID of the Database-Entity I'm working on, along with some other data. The view model is changed accordingly to the users input. What other options than storing it in a session do I have to get a reference to my ViewModel upon requests reaching the controller (like the Save-Method being called in the end and some other methods during the user's interaction with the view).

Comment: Since you appear to be new to DI, I highly recommend [this video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2014/DEV-B412). And since Unity and Ninject both got mentions, I figured I'd toss AutoFac into the mix as well, as I prefer its syntax and find it slightly less verbose to setup than Ninject and I have not used Unity.

Comment: I changed all my DI from Unity to Autofac when MS moved out of it. Other devs here use Ninject. To each their own.

Comment: @Roper - You don't need to store in session. Controller [GET] builds model/viewmodel, passes it to view, when view is submitted back to Controller[POST] [MVC model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding) handles all that behind the scenes. For items without controls like your PK, just add a hidden field (Html.HiddenFor).

Comment: Thanks for all your input. I picked Ninject cause it seemed very easy to use and introduced it into my application based on this tutorial
http://mahedee.net/dependency-injection-using-ninject-in-asp-net-mvc/
Everything seems to work just fine now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you've redacted too much of your code in an effort to "simplify" the question, and as a result, have actually obscured some important issues. However, based on the `Save` method you've posted, I can pretty well guess your issue. Your repo is most likely creating it's own context, which is a pretty big no-no.

To answer you overall question, the rationale for implementing `IDisposable` here is the same as anywhere else: any class that *owns* dependencies that implement `IDisposable` should also implement `IDisposable`. Here, your controller instantiates `MyContext`, so it should therefore dispose of `MyContext` when its done. Simple as that.

However, if you introduce dependency injection, and inject the context into the controller, then the controller no longer *owns* the context. Instead, the DI container will own it. Therefore, your controller should *not* dispose of the context, as it does not own it.

And, you should use dependency injection here. Your context should be injected into your repository and then your repository should be injected into your controller. This ensures that there's is only one context instance, and you won't have issues like you're experiencing now, where EF complains that the entity belongs to a different context.

Finally, I just want to parrot @SteveGreene in saying that there is absolutely no reason to store your entity in the session, and in fact there's many reasons you shouldn't, not the least of which being it will frustrate any efforts to move away from In Proc sessions to a more reliable session store. Once you're using something like StateServer, SQL Server, Redis, etc., anything you put in the session *must* be serializable, and entities are often quite difficult if not impossible to serialize, since they often have many relationships with other entities and often circular relationships with those entities.

Comment: Just to get things straight for me:
Would the DI container hold a single context and just inject it or would it create a new context one for each instantiation of a new Controller (which occurs for every request to a method in the controller being made!?). The second behavior shouldn't be any different from my current one, as there are still multiple short living contexts over time for which no one can be sure if they have been disposed at any particular point in time.

I'm also happy to get some recommendations for IoC containers to use here with ASP.NET MVC and EF.

Comment: You would create the context in "request" scope. It may be called something else based on the particular container, but they pretty much all have some kind of scope that will be tied to the request lifecycle. It just so happens that this will have the effect of injecting a new context per instantiation of the controller, since the controller is instantiated for each request, but that's not really what you should think about.